# Forwarding domain with masking doesn't work on smartphones, but redirecting shows IP address in address bar

Tags: url, domain-forwarding

I have a website on WordPress with a responsive theme. It is located on my server hosted by Apache. Everything works well when I access the website with its IP address. The problem is when I try forward my domain to this address.

I have two options on my domain control panel:

1. Forward `example.com` on IP address `http://192.0.2.1:8080/website`
   Result: When I type `example.com` in browser I see the `example.com` URL but the website does not load corectly on smartphones
2. Forward 301 `example.com` on IP address `http://192.0.2.1:8080/website` Result: Type `example.com`, website loads corectly on mobiles but in url I see `http://192.0.2.1:8080/website` where I wanted to see `example.com`

I know that in the first case the problem is that domain forwarding adds iframe to site and that is why the responsive view does not load.

I want to use 301 zforwarding and mask the URL with `example.com`. How can I achieve this on WordPress?

Comment: What you are trying to do does not make sense to me at all! Why are you forwarding a domain name to an IP address when the domain name translates to the IP address? Seems ridiculously redundant. If you need access to port 8080 you can just access it with example.com:8080.

Comment: "I want to use 301 forwarding and mask url with domain.com." - You can't 301 redirect _and_ mask the URL. You would need to proxy the request (which I doubt that you can from your domain registrar - assuming that is where you are referring to). But why aren't you using DNS (as closetnoc suggests)? Do you specifically want to hide the port and pretend to your users that it's on port 80?

Comment: *Do you specifically want to hide the port and pretend to your users that it's on port 80?* If this is the case, then a *proxy* is required. This is not for the faint at heart! For this, you will really need to know what you are doing and secure your system thoroughly. This is not always a simple task. Using a *proxy* can open your system to significant abuse and and vulnerabilities that you may not be ready for. The *proxy* you use will depend upon on criteria that will likely make the answer to long for a Q&A format. Whole volumes are written on the highly technical subject. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I am taking from your question so I will cover them both.

**Make `http://111.111.111.111:8080/website` Appear as `http://www.domain.com:8080/website`**
In this instance all you need to do is setup a standard DNS record pointing `www.domain.com` to your server's IP address. The important thing to note here is that DNS just translates a domain name to an IP address, the port number and file path must be in the address bar as well.

**Make `http://111.111.111.111:8080/website` Appear as `http://www.domain.com`**
In order to make this work you need to setup a proxy server. A proxy server works by translating the URL you are requesting into something else. Commonly used to provide external access into internal company sites (such as allowing you to access `intranet.local` externally of the local network with the address `intranet.domain.com`). This would allow you to hide the IP address, port number, and even the site specific path (so that `www.domain.com/about/something.html` would allow access to `http://111.111.111.111:8080/website/about/something.html` through the proxy). The difficulty here is securing the proxy environment. A poorly secured proxy server can be a huge security hole into your local network, and can also be used as a launching point to attack or spam other websites and appear as though to be coming from your network. This can get extremely complicated to do and is not for someone without experience in network security and at least an awareness of network protocols. The vastly better solution if possible would be to change the port that serves the HTTP requests from 8080 to port 80 which is the standard HTTP port and so can be ommitted from a HTTP request as no specified port in HTTP is taken to mean port 80.