# Clicking on links doesn't show the full URL when forwarding my domain with masking

Tags: domains, godaddy

I've a domain purchased from godaddy and i want to host it to my local ip. the local IP i have stays same always and I've already set it up to access able globally.

Now in Manage DNS settings of godaddy I've used **Forwarding** section and have forwarded the domain to my ip with masking and now when i open my domain **tvsheevi.com** it opens my website as well but the problem is when i goto my sub-pages it didn't show the complete link

like it should show tvsheevi.com/watch-game-of-thrones-online but it always show only tvsheevi.com.

I'm a web developer and have very less experience with domain hosting and masking i know i am doing something wrong, either this way i've used to mask my domain isn't correct or i am doing it wrong.

If any one can help out it would be great. check attached image for my forwarding settings
[image]

Thanks

Comment: See also [Forwarding domain with masking doesn't work on smartphones, but redirecting shows IP address in address bar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103519/forwarding-domain-with-masking-doesnt-work-on-smartphones-but-redirecting-show) which is a very similar problem

Answer (score 1):

You should not use forwarding which is basically for secondary domains you don't want to be visible.

To use your domain as main entry, you should use a dns redirection on GoDD to your server where you host your website.

Then on this server create a virtual host (if on Apache) to point your domain to the directory of your website.